# Creating API for Model component of a MVC application

Tags: java, api, multi-module

I have a Web MVC application in Spring. I am using JSPs for View component, Spring for controller component. And the model component is divided into technical layers:

1. Service Layer.
2. Business Layer.
3. And Data Access Layer.

Everything works fine. But now, I want to covert my project in to a multi-module Maven project. And want to covert the model component into a library that can be used by other modules. I understand this can done by creating a new module under my main project and add my model layers to it and build it as a jar. But I am not sure how to build API for this module so I can hide my code in this module and expose it through interfaces in API only. Can somebody point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maven module is built as JAR and this JAR is included into another module by it's dependency. API is just service classes with public method. There is no "hiding" code. I don't really understand your problem. It seems you don't have experience with maven multi module project, you should check out some examples first.

Comment: @Gondy I have worked on multi-module projects but I don't have much experience with developing APIs. But as far as I know encapsulation is big part of API design.

Comment: How does your API look like? Or how do you imagine it?